# Rails models: has_many_and_belongs_to_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

I have two models with a has_many association.  However, from the "many", only one is primary.  Here's one way to design it:

### Approach #1

```
class Person < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :address

  def find_primary
    self.address.where('is_primary = ?', "true").first
  end
end

class Address < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :person
  attr_protected :is_primary

  def make_primary
    self.person.address.each { |a| a.update_attribute(:is_primary, false) }
    self.update_attribute(:is_primary,true)
  end

  def is_primary?
    self.is_primary
  end
end
```

I don't like how `make_primary` is O(n) for number of addresses of that person.  It could also be a problem in a multi-threaded environment (i.e. passenger, right?).  Maybe there's an optimization for `make_primary` that could work better for approach #2?

Also, there could easily have hard-to-spot bugs that allow multiple addresses to be primary.

### Approach #2

```
class Person < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :address
  belongs_to :primary_address, :class_name => 'Address', :foreign_key => :primary_address_id
end

class Address < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_one :person_as_primary, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => :primary_address_id

  def make_primary
    self.person.primary_address = self
    self.save!
  end
end
```

Aside from avoiding the multi-threading and O(n) issues, this approach makes `find_primary` unnecessary, since it's simply `self.primary_address`.

However, the concern here is that there's no guarantee that

```
[person, nil].include?(person.primary_address.person_as_primary)
```

Here are my questions:

1)Are there additional advantages/disadvantages that I failed to mention?

2) What other approaches should I consider?  In particular, are there any that don't raise any of the above issues?

Comment: `person.primary_address.person == person` is identity. The relation between person and primary address is within address_id in the Person table. Merely adding the has_one person_as_primary does not change that fact. Also, if you add the :inverse_of option to that relation, ActiveRecord will guarantee that person and person.primary_address.person are the same ruby object

Comment: @JeffPaquette, I fixed my question. I meant person.primary_address.person_as_primary

Answer (score 0):

I would push the solution down to the database in the form of a unique index. This guarantees that only one can be primary at a time. If concurrency wasn't an issue then you could use uniqueness constraints at the Rails level but it sounds like concurrency is a concern for your app.